# Convert key code to string in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, keyboard

I am using Actionscript 3 in Flash CS6 using the Adobe AIR 3.4 for Desktop runtime.

I have certain key codes defined as integer values (example below returns 38 for UP and 68 for D)

```
var KEY_UP:uint = Keyboard.UP;
var KEY_D:uint = Keybaord.D;
```

However, I need to display the keys to the keys to the user (and obviously cannot display the integer values).

How can I convert these keyboard values to a string value such as "Up" or "D" (instead of 38 and 68)?

Comment: try: `trace( String.fromCharCode(Keyboard.D))` , but in case of `UP` it is useless

Comment: That's really useful, thanks. But is there anything I can do to get keys such as `UP` or `SHIFT`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get property name with `describeType`, and access property as String such as `Keyboard["UP"]`.

So, you can create table. For example

```
import flash.utils.describeType;

function getKeyboardDict():Dictionary {
    var keyDescription:XML = describeType(Keyboard);
    var keyNames:XMLList = keyDescription..constant.@name;

    var keyboardDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    var len:int = keyNames.length();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < len; i++) {
        keyboardDict[Keyboard[keyNames[i]]] = keyNames[i];
    }

    return keyboardDict;
}

var keyDict:Dictionary = getKeyboardDict();

trace(keyDict[Keyboard.UP]); //UP
trace(keyDict[Keyboard.SHIFT]); //SHIFT
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I'm mesmerized by this code.  Thanks for this!  I know it was 5 years ago, but still.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenFL with Haxe, you can go to `Keyboard.hx` in `openfl/ui` and use a regexp in a text editor (like Vim or Gedit) on the contents of the file to generate a keyCode to string dictionary.

Use this to create a switch:

```
:%s/\([A-Z_0-9]*\)\ =\ \([0-9]*\)/case \2\: return "\1"/g
```